# Write a Bernoulli distributed random variable using uniforms

Tags: probability, independence, bernoulli-distribution, bernoulli-process

Consider the real-valued random variables $\{X_{ij}\}_{\forall (i,j)\in \mathbb{N}^2, i<j}$ and the real-valued random variables $(\xi_0, \{\xi_i\}_{\forall i \in \mathbb{N}})$, where $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of natural numbers without zero.

In what follows $Be$ denotes "Bernoulli distribution".

Suppose that, $\forall (i,j)\in \mathbb{N}^2, i<j$

$$
X_{ij}|\xi_0, \xi_i, \xi_j\sim Be(w(\xi_0, \xi_i, \xi_j)) \hspace{1cm}(\star)
$$

where $w: \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow [0,1]$ is a Borel measurable map.

Is $(\star)$ equivalent to say that, $\forall (i,j)\in \mathbb{N}^2, i<j$
$$
X_{ij}=1\{\zeta_{ij}\leq w(\xi_0, \xi_i, \xi_j)\} \hspace{1cm}(\star\star)
$$
for some random variables $\{\zeta_{ij}\}_{\forall (i,j)\in \mathbb{N}^2, i<j}$ all uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and such that, $\forall (i,j)\in \mathbb{N}^2$ with $i<j$, $\zeta_{ij}$ is independent of $(\xi_0, \{\xi_i\}_{\forall i \in \mathbb{N}})$?

Clearly $(\star \star)\Rightarrow (\star)$. Is it also true that $(\star \star)\Leftarrow (\star)$?

---

**My attempt** is: we cannot say that $(\star)$ implies $(\star \star)$. Indeed, take for example
$$
X_{ij}=1\{A>\frac{1}{3}\} \hspace{1cm} A\sim U([0,1])
$$
$$
\tilde{X}_{ij}=1\{B\leq \frac{2}{3}\} \hspace{1cm} B\sim U([0,1])
$$
We have that $X_{ij}\sim Be(\frac{2}{3})$ and $\tilde{X}_{ij}\sim Be(\frac{2}{3})$ but $X_{ij}\neq \tilde{X}_{ij}$

---

However, can we more generally say that $(\star)$ implies that there exists a Borel measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ such that
$$
X_{ij}=f(\zeta_{ij}, \xi_0, \xi_i, \xi_j)
$$
for some real-valued random variables $\{\zeta_{ij}\}_{\forall (i,j)\in \mathbb{N}^2, i<j}$, where $Pr(f(\zeta_{ij}, \xi_0, \xi_i, \xi_j)=1| \xi_0, \xi_i, \xi_j)\equiv w(\xi_0, \xi_i, \xi_j)$?

Comment: Please explain your notation.  In particular, although we might guess that "Be" means a Bernoulli distribution, what exactly does "$w$" stand for and what properties are you assuming it has?

Comment: I have added some clarifications on $w$. Thank you